# window.opener difrents button and input type=button

Tags: javascript, window.opener

Salut.
I have proved with Firefox an IE.

If you call paginaH1.html(function openSon) from button (window.opener not work).

if you call from input type=button work.

If you click button not work(a0-ObjectWindow,a1-Undefined).

if you click input type='button' work(a0-ObjectWindow,a1-ObjectHTMLElement).

This is the page opener:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>prueba-Father</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">

 function openSon() {
 window.datoPField = document.frmName.campoPadre;
 alert(window.datoPField+' ahora abro hijo');
 a=window.open('paginaH1.html');
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form  name="frmName">
 <h1 id="text">Comunicacion entre dos paginas con Javascript.</h1>
 <input type="text" name="campoPadre" id="campoPadre" value="delPadre"  >
 <input type="button" onClick="openSon()" value="input-button">
 <button              onClick="openSon()">button</button>
 <button              onClick="window.datoPField = document.getElementById('campoPadre'); a=window.open('paginaH1.html');">bt+getElement</button>
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now pagninaH1.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Son page</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function iniciar() {
 alert(0);
 alert("a0-"+window.opener);
 alert("a1-"+window.opener.datoPField);
 alert("b0-"+window.opener.frmName.campoPadre);
 alert("c0-"+window.opener.datoPField.value);
 this.datoField   = opener.datoPField;
 alert("d0-"+this.datoField);
 }

 </script>

 </head>
 <body ONLOAD="iniciar()">
 <h1 id="text">esta es la pagina hijo </h1>
 <button onclick="this.window.close();">Cerrar</button>
 </body>
</html>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default `type`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-button-type) of `button` elements is `submit`. That is, `<button>x</button>` is exactly the same as `<button type="submit">x</button>`. When you have a `button` in a `form` (which you do), clicking it submits the form after running its click handlers. `form` elements that have no `action` default to submitting to the URL of the page, which destroys the current page and replaces it with a fresh copy (which it's easy to miss).

So when you click the `input`, it runs its click handler, starts the process of opening the popup, and doesn't do anything else. The original window, document, and elements of the opener page still exist. The child window can access those elements.

But when you click the `button`, it runs its click handler, starts the process of opening the popup, and then submits the form, destroying the window, document, and elements. The child window can't access the elements, they don't exist anymore. (Instead, *new* elements exist, but the child doesn't have access to them.)

If you want the `button` to behave the same way the `input` does, add `type="button"` to it. (And yes, saying `<button type="button" ...>` *does* seem ridiculous. :-) )

Comment: Thansk, thanks a lot.<button type="button" ...> does seem ridiculous, but it work. Also thaks for the explanations about the handlers